# Issue with Per-Controller configuration in WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to write a custom controller configuration attribute, and the configuration doesn't seem to be taking, the requests are not using our custom contract resolver, here is what our code looks like in the class that implements the IControllerConfiguration.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

namespace OurCoolStuff.Api.Common.Attributes
{
    public class SuperAwesomeCustomConfig: Attribute, IControllerConfiguration
    {
        public void Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
        {
            controllerSettings.Formatters.Clear();
            controllerSettings.Formatters.Add(GetCustomContractResolver());
        }

        private MediaTypeFormatter GetCustomContractResolver()
        {
            var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
            {
                SerializerSettings =
                {
                    ContractResolver = new OurSuperCoolCustomContractResolver()
                }
            };
            return formatter;
        }
    }
}
```

Then we just use it very simply like:

```
[SuperAwesomeCustomConfig]
TestController : ApiController{
...Controller methods here
}
```

We have tried inserting breakpoints inside of the SuperAwesomeCustomConfig class, and initialize methods, but they never got hit.

Two things to note:
Our controller methods are returning `Task<>` with `async` and we are also using unity for dependency injection.

Our unity code looks like this in UnityConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterComponents()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
        }
```

As far as I can tell this is pretty boilerplate.

Comment: whats your dependency injection related code?

Comment: Updated with Unity code.

Comment: Ok, but I highly doubt that problem is in your dependency injection related code with Unity, may be you trying use those services in controller which is not register with Unity

Comment: Yea I don't think the problem is Unity either.

Comment: When I use the immediate window to look at the loaded formatters, the custom formatter isn't there, which I expected. Just confirming.

Comment: Did you able to hit the GetCustomContractResolver method in debug mode?

Comment: Ok! I inherited from JsonMediaTypeFormatter, to see if the formatter is getting loaded, and IT IS! I now think the problem is in our ContractResolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that the ContractResolver we were using was looking at the wrong types, so in short everything was working as intended. I should have spent more time digging into the problem. Shameless plug for linqpad, as that allowed us to figure out what was wrong with our custom ContractResolver.